# Metadata and Assembley errors After saving the project in the cloud?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-boilerplate

I saved my **Asp.Net Zero** project in *Google drive* Before re-installing windows 10 in the work-station of my company.

Re-opening the project i was surprised with the repeated [CS0234](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0234) and [CS0246](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246) errors:

[image: CS0234_CS0236]

so in the project i get many underlined types or namespaces and unused directives:

[image: metadata errors]

When i build the solution , i get in output these type of errors :

```
 CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\PhoneBookDemo2\src\Acme.PhoneBookDemo.Application\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Acme.PhoneBookDemo.Application.dll' could not be found
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing the initial project with my project, i was surprised that there is missing files ( that means google drive missed the upload of these files), copying these files to my project fixed the issue.